# How do you use Apache SetEnvIf with cookie values?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to control apache based on cookie values, but I can't seem to get `SetEnvIf` to work with `HTTP_COOKIE`. I've boiled this down to some simple logic to isolate the issue and be easy to test.

Apache 2.2.22 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

---

What I'm using is:

```
     Header set Set-Cookie "cookie1=1"
     SetEnvIf HTTP_COOKIE "cookie1=1" is_cookie1
     Header set Set-Cookie "cookie2=2" env=is_cookie1
```

Using Chrome's resources tab, I am inspecting the cookies for the page. What I expect to see is:

- First page load, `cookie1=1` exists
- Second (and subsequent) page loads, `cookie1=1` and `cookie2=2` exist.

Instead, all I ever get is `cookie1`:

[image: Chrome cookie inspector]

---

If I add the line:

```
     SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^192\.168\. is_cookie1
```

Then `cookie2` is set immediately, as I'd expect, so the last `Header ... env=is_cookie1` line appears to be fine.

---

I also tried to verify that HTTP_COOKIE was being set correctly:

```
     RewriteRule ^/test/$ /test/%{HTTP_COOKIE} [R=302,L]
```

Now going to `/test/` immediately redirects to `/test/cookie1=1%3b%20cookie2=2` as I was expecting, and so `HTTP_COOKIE` seems to be set properly.

---

I've also tried a bunch of variations of SetEnvIf and nothing seems to work:

```
     SetEnvIf HTTP_COOKIE "^cookie1=1$" is_cookie1
     SetEnvIf HTTP_COOKIE ^cookie1=1$ is_cookie1
     SetEnvIf HTTP_COOKIE "^.+$" is_cookie1
     SetEnvIf HTTP_COOKIE ^.+$ is_cookie1
```

..although

```
     SetEnvIf HTTP_COOKIE ^.*$ is_cookie1
```

sets cookie2 immediately (on first load) in any situation (which... is not useful at all. but at least it tells me this line does *something*).

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue and this page comes at the top of Google for `apache setenvif cookie` so I thought I would share how I fixed this.

I was able to match against the cookies by using the `Cookie` variable rather than the `HTTP_COOKIE` variable, i.e.

```
SetEnvIf Cookie "cookie1=1" is_cookie1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but I can offer 2 things:

1. a hunch that even though you've ordered the *directives* properly [Header... SetEnvIf... Header...], the order of processing of the relevant *modules* providing those directives might make their interplay an issue. Which suggests an alternate angle of attack might be worth trying.
2. a different mechanism for the cookie-setting might help: try using a mod_rewrite RewriteRule that does not actually route the request (note the "-" target), but merely sets a cookie:

   RewriteRule ^/index.html - [CO=cookiename:cookieval:.example.com:1440:/]

You can add a RewriteCond to check for the env var and thus conditionally set the cookie like this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:VARNAME} value
RewriteRule ^/index\.html - [CO=cookiename:cookieval:.example.com:1440:/]
```

It might even meet your requirements to skip setting env vars altogether and just set the 2nd cookie based on the presence of the 1st, keeping all the logic within mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookie1
RewriteRule ^/index\.html - [CO=cookie2:2:.example.com:1440:/]
```

HTH! :)
Chris